# The query function on a window resize function is not working

Tags: jquery

I have made a same height function for the image, name and description, but it's not working on window resize.

I am trying to use this function  `$(window).bind('load resize')` but it's not working so far.

```js
function sameHeight(c, scope) {
          if (scope) {
            $(scope).each(function() {
              var set = $(this).find(c);
              sameHeight(set);
            });
          } else {
            var h = 0;
            $(c).each(function() {
              var th = $(this).height()
              h = (th > h) ? th : h;
            });
            $(c).height(h);
          }
        }

        // centre the image vertically within the div 
        function centreImg(c) {
          $(c).each(function() {
            var imgHeight = $(this).find('img').height();
            var boxHeight = $(this).height();
            var padTop = Math.floor((boxHeight - imgHeight) / 2);
            $(this).find('img').css('marginTop', padTop);
          });
        }

        window.doSameHeight = function() {
          // element, scope
          // replace below with elements that the script needs to affect
          sameHeight('.featured-product-image', '.product-row');
          sameHeight('.featured-product-name', '.product-row');
          sameHeight('.featured-product-desc', '.product-row');
          centreImg('.product-row .featured-product-image');
        }

        $(window).bind('load resize', function() {
          window.doSameHeight();
        });
```

```css
.cf:before,.cf:after {content: ""; display: table;}
.cf:after {clear: both}
.cf {zoom: 1}

.featured-product {
    width: 32.33333333%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ecedeb;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
.featured-product-image {
    text-align: center;
}
.featured-product-image img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.featured-product-name {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1c2023;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}
.featured-product-name a {
    font-family: 'Vollkorn', serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #1c2023;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.featured-product-name a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #3f6751;
}
.featured-product-desc {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #1b1f22;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
}
.featured-product-cart {
    width: 182px;
    background-color: #3f6751;
    float: left;
}
.featured-product-price {
    width: 133px;
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #1b1f22;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    line-height: 60px;
    height: 65px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-row cf">
  <div class="featured-product i-1">
    <div class="featured-product-image"> <a href="1-piece-premium-e-cig-kit-375-p.asp" data-ekm-badges="" data-ekm-badges-max-width="90.8" data-ekm-badges-max-height="90.8"><img itemprop="image" src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/images/1-piece-premium-e-cig-kit-capacity-75ml-377-p[ekm]227x227[ekm].jpg" alt="1 Piece Premium E Cig Kit" id="_EKM_SHOWDATA_PRODUCT_375" border="0"
        /></a> </div>
    <!--featured product image-->
    <div class="featured-product-name"><a href="1-piece-premium-e-cig-kit-375-p.asp">1 Piece Premium E Cig Kit</a></div>
    <!--featured product name-->
    <div class="featured-product-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne duo urbanitas eloquentiam consectetuer, vel et stet complectitur intellegebat, malorum alterum mei no. Ut alii reprehendunt cum, homero munere mentitum mei eu. </div>
    <!--featured product desc-->
    <div class="featured-product-cart-container cf">
      <div class="featured-product-cart"> <a href="index.asp?function=CART&mode=ADD&productid=375"> <span class="add-to-cart"> Add to Cart</span><span class="add-cart-icon"><img src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/resources/design/add-to-cart.png" /></span></a> </div>
      <!--featured product cart-->
      <div class="featured-product-price"><span class="product-price">&#163;54.99<span class="product-rrp">&#163;49.99</span></span> </div>
      <!--------featured product price---------> 
    </div>
    <!--featured product cart container--> 
  </div>
  <!--featured product-->
  <div class="featured-product i-2">
    <div class="featured-product-image"> <a href="3-piece-e-cig-kit-with-carry-case-3-piece-e-cig-kit-with-carry-case-367-p.asp" data-ekm-badges="" data-ekm-badges-max-width="90.8" data-ekm-badges-max-height="90.8"><img itemprop="image" src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/images/1-piece-premium-e-cig-kit-capacity-75ml-377-p[ekm]227x227[ekm].jpg" alt="3 Piece E Cig Kit with Carry Case 3 Piece E Cig Kit with Carry Case"
        id="_EKM_SHOWDATA_PRODUCT_367" border="0" /></a> </div>
    <!--featured product image-->
    <div class="featured-product-name"><a href="3-piece-e-cig-kit-with-carry-case-3-piece-e-cig-kit-with-carry-case-367-p.asp">3 Piece E Cig Kit with Carry Case 3 Piece E Cig Kit with Carry Case</a></div>
    <!--featured product name-->
    <div class="featured-product-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne duo urbanitas eloquentiam consectetuer.</div>
    <!--featured product desc-->
    <div class="featured-product-cart-container cf">
      <div class="featured-product-cart"> <a href="index.asp?function=CART&mode=ADD&productid=367"> <span class="add-to-cart"> Add to Cart</span><span class="add-cart-icon"><img src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/resources/design/add-to-cart.png" /></span></a> </div>
      <!--featured product cart-->
      <div class="featured-product-price"><span class="product-price">&#163;54.99<span class="product-rrp">&#163;49.99</span></span> </div>
      <!--------featured product price---------> 
    </div>
    <!--featured product cart container--> 
  </div>
  <!--featured product-->
  <div class="featured-product i-3">
    <div class="featured-product-image"> <a href="black-e-cig-case-396-p.asp" data-ekm-badges="" data-ekm-badges-max-width="90.8" data-ekm-badges-max-height="90.8"><img itemprop="image" src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/images/1-piece-premium-e-cig-kit-capacity-75ml-377-p[ekm]227x227[ekm].jpg" alt="Black E Cig Case" id="_EKM_SHOWDATA_PRODUCT_396" border="0"
        /></a> </div>
    <!--featured product image-->
    <div class="featured-product-name"><a href="black-e-cig-case-396-p.asp">Black E Cig Case</a></div>
    <!--featured product name-->
    <div class="featured-product-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ne duo urbanitas eloquentiam consectetuer, vel et stet complectitur intellegebat, malorum alterum mei no. Ut alii reprehendunt cum, homero munere mentitum mei eu.</div>
    <!--featured product desc-->
    <div class="featured-product-cart-container cf">
      <div class="featured-product-cart"> <a href="index.asp?function=CART&mode=ADD&productid=396"> <span class="add-to-cart"> Add to Cart</span><span class="add-cart-icon"><img src="http://www.ekmpowershop18.com/ekmps/shops/jonny_lomax/resources/design/add-to-cart.png" /></span></a> </div>
      <!--featured product cart-->
      <div class="featured-product-price"><span class="product-price">&#163;9.99<span class="product-rrp">&#163;14.99</span></span> </div>
      <!--------featured product price---------> 
    </div>
    <!--featured product cart container--> 
  </div>
  <!--featured product--> 
</div>
```

Comment: Did you to change `$(window).bind('load resize',` to `$(window).on('load resize',`? Did that work?

Comment: I have checked already "$(window).on('load resize',", but this is not working

Comment: minimal text tweak